# Good example of where move semantics would be beneficial

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, copy, move

**EDIT: I want the code below to be slow (and do excessive copying) so that I can re-write it using move semantics and compare the two approaches.**

I have the following code in a class:

```
std::list<boost::shared_ptr<I> > getX(){
    std::list<boost::shared_ptr<I> > a;

    for(auto kv : b) {
        if(something){
            a.push_back(kv.second);
        }
    } 

    return a;
}

double foo(){

    std::list<boost::shared_ptr<I> > a = getX();
```

Now I put a break point on `return a` and I was expecting to see some sort of copy of the list being made (the `std::list` copy constructor and then each `I` object copy constructor. However, instead the debugger broke in to amdsecgs.asm:

```
LEAF_ENTRY __security_check_cookie, _TEXT

cmp rcx, __security_cookie      ; check cookie value in frame
jne ReportFailure               ; if ne, cookie check failure
rol rcx, 16                     ; make sure high word is zero
test cx, -1
jne RestoreRcx
db 0f3h                         ; (encode REP for REP RET)
ret                             ; no overrun, use REP RET to avoid AMD
                                ; branch prediction flaw after Jcc
```

and I wasn't able to see any copy of the list being made. I was hoping to see the list copied and then each of the I objects being copied.

(The reason I am asking this is because I am trying to write some code which would be great to speed-up using move semantics).

Is this code being optimised via return-value optimisation? If so, is there any way I could tinker with the code to prevent RVO being applied?

Comment: my understanding is that you are still copying the list to return it by copy (because the original list is a stack automatic object and gets destroyed when it comes out of scope), it just isn't copied again when it gets assigned to a because of the move semantics.

Why are you now creating your list in the heap and just returning a smart pointer instead? That would eliminate all copying.

Comment: @Julius I WANT to create copies to demonstrate (by re-writing the code) the advantages of move semantics....

Answer (score 0):

One option could be:

```
std::list<boost::shared_ptr<I> > getX(){
    using list = std::list<boost::shared_ptr<I> >;
    list empty;
    list a;

    for(auto kv : b) {
        if(something){
            a.push_back(kv.second);
        }
    } 

    return list( a.empty() ? empty : a );
}
```

That should break RVO/NRVO and force the compiler to copy the list that is returned.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is only to demonstrate the speedup provided by move semantics, you could use a case where you don't actually have to fight the compiler for it to be useful, like when moving automatic scoped collections within their scope, like so:

```
typedef vector<float> Grades;
unordered_map<int, string> idsToNames;
unordered_map<int, Grades> idsToGrades;
//ids and names being used seperatly
...
//it would now be more useful to merge them
struct StudentInfo {
    string mName; Grades mGrades; 
    StudentInfo(string && name, Grades && grades):mName(name),mGrades(grades){}
};

unordered_map<int, StudentInfo> idsToStudentInfo;

for(pair<int, string>& s : idsToNames)  {
    idsToStudentInfo.insert(
         make_pair(s.first, 
             StudentInfo(std::move(s.second),std::move(idsToGrades[s.first]))
         )
    );
}
```

So here, instead of copying the Grades vectors and the strings (char vectors), they just get swapped in the move constructors of the mName string and of the mGrades string, being quite faster.